# How do you call a constructor via an expression tree on an existing object?

Tags: c#, serialization, expression-trees

I'm trying to call the deserialization constructor for an object that already exists. How do I do that with expression trees?

I tried:

```
// Create an uninitialized object
T graph = (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(graphType);

// (graph, serializationInfo, streamingContext) => graph.Constructor(serializationInfo, streamingContext)
ParameterExpression graphParameter = Expression.Parameter(serializationPack.SelfSerializingBaseClassType, "graph");
ParameterExpression serializationInfoParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SerializationInfo), "serializationInfo");
ParameterExpression streamingContextParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StreamingContext), "streamingContext");

MethodCallExpression callDeserializationConstructor = Expression.Call(graphParameter,
    (MethodInfo)serializationPack.SelfSerializingBaseClassType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(SerializationInfo), typeof(StreamingContext) }), 
        new[] { serializationInfoParameter, streamingContextParameter });
```

but `Expression.Call` only accepts `MethodInfo` not `ConstructorInfo`, so that doesn't work - unless there is a way to convert to a `MethodInfo`?

**Update**

I eneded up just using `ConstructorInfo.Invoke`:

```
// Cache this part
ConstructorInfo deserializationConstructor = serializationPack
    .SelfSerializingBaseClassType
    .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Standard,
        new[] { typeof(SerializationInfo), typeof(StreamingContext) }, null);

// Call this when I need it
deserializationConstructor.Invoke(graph, new Object[] { serializationInfo, new StreamingContext() });
```

I'm scared of the performance on it, but it seems to be the only way to do this.

**Update**

This has a proper answer now. Thanks all.

Comment: “How do I do that with expression trees?” Why do you think you can do that with expression trees, when you can't do it with normal code?

Comment: Call a constructor on an existing object? You can do that. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Tomorrow I will produce some code.

Comment: Looking forward with anticipation.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could use reflection to do this, this is evil. I think that you should never do this, unless absolutely necessary. A constructor should run exactly once for each object (unless you use constructor chaining).

Comment: Right, but as I mentioned, I'm trying to call the deserialization constructor for a base class on an already existing object. Regular `[Serializable]` stuff I deserialize myself, but for self-deserializing stuff (things that implement `ISerializable`) you have to find some way to call it's deserialization constructor. This is +1 messy when the base class is `ISerializable`, yet the derived class is `[Serializable]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you don't really care whether the constructor is called via an expression tree, so long as the actual invocation doesn't require reflection. You can build a dynamic method that forwards to a constructor call:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var constructor = typeof(Foo).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
            var helperMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(Foo) }, typeof(Foo).Module, true);
            var ilGenerator = helperMethod.GetILGenerator();
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, constructor);
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            var constructorInvoker = (Action<Foo>)helperMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Foo>));

            var foo = Foo.Create();
            constructorInvoker(foo);
            constructorInvoker(foo);
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        int x;

        public static Foo Create()
        {
            return new Foo();
        }

        private Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor Foo() called, GetHashCode() returns {0}, x is {1}", GetHashCode(), x);
            x++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Note though that this behaves like a regular method call. `x` is not set before printing its value, so it does not get reset to `0` when you call the constructor again. Depending on what your constructor does, this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: This appears to be the answer. Thank yous.

Comment: @sircodesalot I forgot to include a warning why this won't work with all classes, please double check to make sure that it's still useful for you :)

Comment: You have 'x' and 'i'. Are they supposed to be the same? I don't quite follow.

Comment: @sircodesalot Yes, they were supposed to be the same, that was a typo. This won't be a problem if you only construct objects once, but if you call the constructor again after it has already been called, the results might not be what you want.

Comment: Ah, I'm using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`, which doesn't do any construction at all. In the general case, I just gut all of the fieldinfo data from the object I'm serializing, and then paste it back onto an empty shell when deserializing. However, stuff that implements `ISerializable` requires that I call the "Deserialization Constructor" in order for it to perform it's own deserialization (hence the question). I assume that if it implements `ISerializable`, it should expect something like this (late construction) to occur.

Comment: I missed that bit, thanks for the explanation, you shouldn't have any problems then.

Comment: Oh uh, one thing. arg_0 is the "this" argument.

Comment: @sircodesalot For instance methods, not for static methods. This behaves like a static method.

Comment: Ah, duh. I forgot. Perfect, Thanks

Comment: Last thing (I hope). I noticed that if I take off the `typeof(Foo).Module` I get "operation may destabilize the runtime". If I leave that portion on though in my current code base, I get "Attempt by method ... to access ...ctor failed". I don't quite get what's happening with that.

Comment: @sircodesalot There's two separate issues: firstly, you aren't normally allowed to use the `call` instruction except in your own module, and `typeof(Foo).Module` treats it as if it's in the same module. Secondly, I'm guessing your constructor is private, in that case you need to use the `DynamicMethod` constructor that takes both `module` and `skipVisibility` arguments. Will update.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. I regret that I have but one point to give. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use expression trees, use [Expression.New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.new.aspx). Here's an example

```
var info = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SerializationInfo), "info");
var context = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StreamingContext), "context");

var callTheCtor = Expression.New(ctorInfo, info, context);
```

This doesn't work on an existing object, but since your code shows `GetUninitializedObject` I would think you could just remove that part and use `Expression.New` to create a new object.

Answer (score 2):

I created a method to create an (open) delegate to the constructor. You can use it with any (static or instance) constructor with any number of arguments and variaty (like ref and out). If your delegate returns void, the instance of the constructed type is expected as the first parameter. If the delegate returns the type to be constructed, a new instance will be created.

```
static public T CreateDelegate<T>(this ConstructorInfo constructor)
{
    // Validate if the constructor is not null.
    if (constructor == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("constructor");

    // Validate if T is a delegate.
    Type delegateType = typeof(T);
    if (!typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(delegateType))
        throw new ArgumentException("Generic argument T must be a delegate.");

    // Get alle needed information.
    MethodInfo invoke = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    ParameterInfo[] constructorParams = constructor.GetParameters();
    ParameterInfo[] delegateParams = invoke.GetParameters();

    // What kind of delegate is going to be created (open, creational, static).
    bool isOpen = false;
    OpCode opCode = OpCodes.Newobj;
    int parameterOffset = 0;
    if (constructor.IsStatic) // Open delegate.
    {
        opCode = OpCodes.Call;
        if (invoke.ReturnType != typeof(void))
            throw new ArgumentException("Delegate to static constructor cannot have a return type.");
        if (delegateParams.Length != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Delegate to static constructor cannot have any parameters.");
    }
    else if (invoke.ReturnType == typeof(void)) // Open delegate.
    {
        opCode = OpCodes.Call;
        isOpen = true;
        parameterOffset = 1;
        if ((delegateParams.Length == 0) || (delegateParams[0].ParameterType != constructor.DeclaringType))
            throw new ArgumentException("An open delegate must have a first argument of the same type as the type that is being constructed.");
    }
    else // Creational delegate.
    {
        if (invoke.ReturnType != constructor.DeclaringType)
            throw new ArgumentException("Return type of delegate must be equal to the type that is being constructed.");
    }

    // Validate the parameters (if any).
    if (constructorParams.Length + parameterOffset != delegateParams.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException(isOpen
            ? "The number of parameters of the delegate (the argument for the instance excluded) must be the same as the number of parameters of the constructor."
            : "The number of parameters of the delegate must be the same as the number of parameters of the constructor.");
    for (int i = 0; i < constructorParams.Length; i++)
    {
        ParameterInfo constructorParam = constructorParams[i];
        ParameterInfo delegateParam = delegateParams[i + parameterOffset];
        if (constructorParam.ParameterType != delegateParam.ParameterType)
            throw new ArgumentException("Arguments of constructor and delegate do not match.");
    }

    // Create the dynamic method.
    DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(
            "",
            invoke.ReturnType,
            delegateParams.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray(),
            constructor.DeclaringType.Module,
            true);


    // Create the IL.
    ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();
    for (int i = 0; i < delegateParams.Length; i++)
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i);
    gen.Emit(opCode, constructor);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // Return the delegate :)
    return (T)(object)method.CreateDelegate(delegateType);
}
```

To create a delegate, use:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(int anyValue)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Action<MyObject, int> c = typeof(MyObject)
    .GetConstructor(new [] { typeof(int) })
    .CreateDelegate<Action<MyObject, int>>();
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(1;
c(myObject, 2);
```

This all can be made a bit shorter by adding an extra function:

```
static public T CreateConstructorDelegate<T>(this Type type)
{
    // Validate if the constructor is not null.
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

    // Validate if T is a delegate.
    Type delegateType = typeof(T);
    if (!typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(delegateType))
        throw new ArgumentException("Generic argument T must be a delegate.");

    // Validate the delegate return type
    MethodInfo invoke = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    int parameterOffset = 0;
    BindingFlags binding = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    if (invoke.ReturnType == typeof(void))
    {
        if (invoke.GetParameters().Length == 0)
            binding = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static; // For static constructors.
        else
            parameterOffset = 1; // For open delegates.
    }
    // Validate the signatures
    ParameterInfo[] delegateParams = invoke.GetParameters();
    ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(binding, null, delegateParams.Skip(parameterOffset).Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray(), null);
    if (constructor == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Constructor with specified parameters cannot be found.");

    return constructor.CreateDelegate<T>();
}
```

The call to create the delegate will now be:

```
Action<MyObject, int> c = typeof(MyObject)
    .CreateConstructorDelegate<Action<MyObject, int>>();
// Call constructor.
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(1);
// Call constructor again on same object.
c(myObject, 2);
```

**Warning!** *Everytime you call these methods, a little piece of code will be created. If you call these functions a lot for the same constructor, think about caching.*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the constructor if the object has already been created. You can see how this method is used in the BCL, all methods marked as `internal` and method to call constructor is implemented within the common language runtime itself:

```
RuntimeConstructorInfo constructor = ObjectManager.GetConstructor(t);
object uninitializedObject = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject((Type) this.m_realType);
constructor.SerializationInvoke(uninitializedObject, this.m_savedSerializationInfo, context);

[DebuggerHidden]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal static void SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, object target, SerializationInfo info, ref StreamingContext context);
```

Comment: `You cannot call the constructor if the object has already been created`. This is not strictly speaking true.