# C# Expression tree: object array to Expression.New() parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, orm, expression-trees

I'd like to use expression trees to improve performance of some object-relational mapping code. The old code looks something like this:

```cs
public List<T> SqlToResults<T>(string query)
{
    // Do SQL stuff, get matching constructor for type T ...
    // ...

    List<T> results = new List<T>();

    // Create buffer for constructor parameters
    object[] constructorParams = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            // simplefied (there'd be some mapping to match correct order of parameters)
            constructorParams[i] = reader[i];
        }
        
        // create new instance of T with our data
        T result = (T)constructorInfoOfT.Invoke(constructorParams);
        
        // add new result to list of results
        results.Add(result);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The performance bottle neck in above code is the call to `ConstructorInfo.Invoke()` which I'd like to replace with an expression tree and a call to `Expression.New()` similar to the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375567/9745732). However at compile time I don't know the number of parameters and their types it seems to be a bit more complicated. `Expression.New()` takes an array of **Expressions** as the argument to the constructor but I only have an array of objects (which would be a single `ParameterExpression`). So I'd somehow have to loop over the content of the `ParameterExpression` to then map every element to it's own `Expression` which then can be passed as an `Expression[]` to `Expression.New()`.

The code I have in mind would look something like this:

```cs
internal delegate TInstance Constructor<TInstance>(object[] parameters);

internal Constructor<T> BuildConstructorFrom<T>(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression constructorParameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));

    Expression[] parameterExpressions;

    // ???
    // somehow map entries in constructorParameters to entries in parameterExpressions 
    // ???

    NewExpression constructorCall = Expression.New(constructorInfo, parameterExpressions);

    Constructor<T> ctor = (Constructor<T>)Expression.Lambda<Constructor<T>>(constructorCall, constructorParameters).Compile();
    return ctor;
}
```

I have taken a look at similar questions like [foreach loop using expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175558/foreach-loop-using-expression-trees) and [issue while building dynamic expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646283/issue-while-building-dynamic-expression-tree) but I'm still unsure as to how to use these loops in my use case.

Comment: You should use `ConstructorInfo.GetParameters` to get the list of parameters expected by the constructor, then create an array (or list) of `ParameterExpression` based on that, while taking care of checking the types of each parameter and perform proper conversions from object. However, you will still have a delegate accepting an array of objects to be passed to the new expression. It works, but its performance is still affected by its generalized approach, where an array of objects contains the values of the parameters. Value boxing could also be involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The solution was to use `Expression.ArrayIndex` and a conventional for loop:

```cs
internal Constructor<T> BuildConstructerFrom<T>(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo)
{
    ParameterExpression constructorParameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object?[]));

    ParameterInfo[] parametersInfos = constructorInfo.GetParameters();

    Expression[] parameterExpressions = new Expression[parametersInfos.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parametersInfos.Length; i++)
    {
        ConstantExpression ithIndex = Expression.Constant(i);
        BinaryExpression ithParameter = Expression.ArrayIndex(constructorParameters, ithIndex);
        UnaryExpression unboxedIthParameter = Expression.Convert(ithParameter, parametersInfos[i].ParameterType);
        parameterExpressions[i] = unboxedIthParameter;
    }

    NewExpression constructorCall = Expression.New(constructorInfo, parameterExpressions);

    Constructor<T> ctor = (Constructor<T>)Expression.Lambda<Constructor<T>>(constructorCall, constructorParameters).Compile();
    return ctor;
}
```